# Is there any documentation of functions in Mercurial cgi interface?

Tags: mercurial, cgi

I am trying to get some information about the different pages served by the [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com) cgi webpage. However I cannot find **anything** usefull. By accident I stumbled upon the *raw-rev* page. Anyone got some valid links to documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an annotated crawl from a recent mercurial installation:

```
.
|-- annotate/REVID/FILEPATH              # HTML: which user last edited each line of the file
|-- atom-log                             # XML : change feed of changelogs
|-- atom-tags                            # XML : change feed of tags
|-- branches                             # HTML: list of named branches
|-- diff/REVID/FILEPATH                  # HTML: show change made to file by REVID
|-- file[/REVID[/FILEPATH]               # HTML: show file as it stood after REVID
|-- graph[/REVID]                        # HTML: log with visual connectivity graph
|-- log[/REVID/FILEPATH]                 # HTML: list of changesets with metadata
|-- raw-annotate/REVID/FILEPATH          # TEXT: raw output version of annotate
|-- raw-file/REVID/FILEPATH              # TEXT: raw output version of file
|-- raw-rev[/REVID]                      # TEXT: raw output version of rev
|-- rev[/REVID]                          # HTML: show all changes made by REVID
|-- rss-log                              # XML : change feed of changelogs
|-- rss-tags                             # XML : change feed of tags
|-- shortlog[/REVID/FILEPATH]            # HTML: slightly more terse version of log
`-- tags                                 # HTML: listing of tags
```

Listing methods (log, tags, branches, graph, shortlog) take &revcount=N, which limits the output length.

Valid REVIDs are found using: `hg help revisions`

FILEPATH must extend from the `hg root` to a single file, excepting for `raw-file` where directories are accepted.